# Varnish 4: Always miss

Tags: performance, caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm currently setting up Varnish 4 for my domain.
My Varnish caches all files like charm, except of the DOC-request.
But I can't figure out, why the DOC-request is always a "MISS".

I hope, that you guys can help me.

All details below. If you need more, tell me.

Thank you so much for your help!

Regards,
Hermsi

Varnish-Version:

```
/ # varnishd -V
varnishd (varnish-4.1.3 revision 5e3b6d2)
Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS
Copyright (c) 2006-2015 Varnish Software AS
```

curl request:

```
$ curl -s -D - "https://www.example.com" -o /dev/null
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 0
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 15 Nov 2017 20:25:14 GMT
Expires: Wed, 15 Nov 2017 20:25:14 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Age:
X-Cache-Grace:
X-Cache-Ttl-Remaining:
X-Hits: 0
X-Host: example.com
X-Varnish-Cookie-Debug: Cleaned request cookies:
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Varnishlog:

```
*   << BeReq    >> 786983
-   Begin          bereq 786982 pass
-   Timestamp      Start: 1510849297.605099 0.000000 0.000000
-   BereqMethod    GET
-   BereqURL       /
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
-   BereqHeader    Host: www.example.com
-   BereqHeader    User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
-   BereqHeader    Accept: */*
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Host: www.example.com
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Server: lb-proxy-1
-   BereqHeader    X-Real-Ip: XXX.XX.XXX.XXX
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: XXX.XX.XXX.XXX
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   BereqHeader    X-Device: desktop
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 786983
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   BackendOpen    23 boot.default XXX.XX.XXX.XXX 80 10.42.70.133 39122
-   BackendStart   XXX.XX.XXX.XXX 80
-   Timestamp      Bereq: 1510849297.619798 0.014699 0.014699
-   Timestamp      Beresp: 1510849297.676958 0.071859 0.057160
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   200
-   BerespReason   OK
-   BerespHeader   Date: Thu, 16 Nov 2017 16:21:37 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Server: Apache
-   BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=0
-   BerespHeader   Expires: Thu, 16 Nov 2017 16:21:37 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
-   BerespHeader   Content-Length: 3252
-   BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   TTL            RFC 0 10 -1 1510849298 1510849298 1510849297 1510849297 0
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
-   BerespHeader   X-Varnish-Cookie-Debug: Cleaned request cookies:
-   BerespHeader   x-url: /
-   BerespHeader   x-host: www.example.com
-   BerespHeader   X-Cache: ZIP
-   BereqHeader    stale-while-revalidate: max-age=0
-   TTL            VCL -1 7200 0 1510849298
-   TTL            VCL 120 7200 0 1510849298
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Storage        malloc Transient
-   ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ObjStatus      200
-   ObjReason      OK
-   ObjHeader      Date: Thu, 16 Nov 2017 16:21:37 GMT
-   ObjHeader      Server: Apache
-   ObjHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=0
-   ObjHeader      Expires: Thu, 16 Nov 2017 16:21:37 GMT
-   ObjHeader      Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   ObjHeader      Content-Encoding: gzip
-   ObjHeader      Content-Length: 3252
-   ObjHeader      Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   ObjHeader      X-Varnish-Cookie-Debug: Cleaned request cookies:
-   ObjHeader      x-url: /
-   ObjHeader      x-host: www.example.com
-   ObjHeader      X-Cache: ZIP
-   Fetch_Body     3 length stream
-   Gzip           u F - 3252 10723 80 80 25946
-   BackendReuse   23 boot.default
-   Timestamp      BerespBody: 1510849297.677148 0.072049 0.000190
-   Length         3252
-   BereqAcct      328 0 328 247 3252 3499
-   End

*   << Request  >> 786982
-   Begin          req 786981 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1510849297.605008 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1510849297.605008 0.000000 0.000000
-   ReqStart       10.42.115.200 35666
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Host: www.example.com
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
-   ReqHeader      Accept: */*
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: XXX.XX.XXX.XXX
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Host: www.example.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Server: lb-proxy-1
-   ReqHeader      X-Real-Ip: XXX.XX.XXX.XXX
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: XXX.XX.XXX.XXX
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: XXX.XX.XXX.XXX, 10.42.115.200
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: XXX.XX.XXX.XXX, 10.42.115.200
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: XXX.XX.XXX.XXX
-   ReqHeader      Cookie:
-   ReqUnset       Cookie:
-   ReqHeader      Cookie:
-   ReqUnset       Cookie:
-   ReqHeader      Cookie:
-   ReqUnset       Cookie:
-   ReqHeader      Cookie:
-   ReqUnset       Cookie:
-   ReqHeader      Cookie:
-   ReqUnset       Cookie:
-   ReqHeader      Cookie:
-   ReqUnset       Cookie:
-   ReqHeader      Cookie:
-   ReqUnset       Cookie:
-   ReqHeader      Cookie:
-   ReqUnset       Cookie:
-   ReqHeader      Cookie:
-   ReqUnset       Cookie:
-   ReqHeader      Cookie:
-   ReqUnset       Cookie:
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   ReqHeader      X-Device: desktop
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   Debug          "XXXX HIT-FOR-PASS"
-   HitPass        786980
-   VCL_call       PASS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 786983 pass
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1510849297.677182 0.072175 0.072175
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     200
-   RespReason     OK
-   RespHeader     Date: Thu, 16 Nov 2017 16:21:37 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Apache
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=0
-   RespHeader     Expires: Thu, 16 Nov 2017 16:21:37 GMT
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 3252
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish-Cookie-Debug: Cleaned request cookies:
-   RespHeader     x-url: /
-   RespHeader     x-host: www.example.com
-   RespHeader     X-Cache: ZIP
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 786982
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespUnset      x-url: /
-   RespUnset      x-host: www.example.com
-   RespUnset      X-Cache: ZIP
-   RespHeader     X-Cache: MISS
-   RespHeader     X-Hits: 0
-   RespHeader     X-Host: example.com
-   RespUnset      Server: Apache
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 786982
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
-   RespHeader     X-Cache-TTL-Remaining:
-   RespHeader     X-Cache-Age:
-   RespHeader     X-Cache-Grace:
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1510849297.677222 0.072215 0.000040
-   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   Debug          "RES_MODE 2"
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1510849297.677275 0.072268 0.000053
-   ReqAcct        290 0 290 446 3252 3698
-   End
```

This is my VCL:

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;

include "cache_invalidation.vcl";
include "custom_subroutines.vcl";

backend default {
    .host = "VARNISH_BACKEND_ADDRESS";  # IP or Hostname of backend
    .port = "VARNISH_BACKEND_PORT";     # Port Apache or whatever is listening
    .connect_timeout = 5s;              # Wait a maximum of 5s for backend connection (Apache, Nginx, etc...)
    .first_byte_timeout = 10s;           # Wait a maximum of 10s for the first byte to come from your backend
    .between_bytes_timeout = 2s;        # Wait a maximum of 2s between each bytes sent
    .max_connections = 300;             # Max parallel connections to our backend
}


sub vcl_recv {

    # IP forwarding.
    if (req.restarts == 0) {
        if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For && !req.http.X-Real-IP) {
            set req.http.X-Real-IP = regsub(req.http.X-Forwarded-For, ".*\b(?!10|127|172)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*", "\1");
        }else{
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Real-IP;
        }
    }

    # Enforce redirect to HTTPS
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto !~ "(?i)https") {
        return(synth(720, "https://" + req.http.host + req.url));
    }

    # Remove the Google Analytics added parameters, useless for our backend
      if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=") {
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "&(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=([A-z0-9_\-\.%25]+)", "");
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "\?(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=([A-z0-9_\-\.%25]+)", "?");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?&", "?");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?$", "");
      }

    # Remove anchor or hash references
      if(req.url ~ "\#"){
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\#.*$", "");
      }

    # Remove incomplete query string
      if(req.url ~ "\?$"){
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?$", "");
      }

    # Remove Google Analytics Cookies, our server does not need it
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__utm.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_ga=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_gat=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmctr=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmcmd.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmccn.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove DoubleClick offensive cookies
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__gads=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the Quant Capital cookies (added by some plugin, all __qca)
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__qc.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the AddThis cookies
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__atuv.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove a ";" prefix in the cookie if present
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");

    # Are there cookies left with only spaces or that are empty?
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }

    if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(bmp|bz2|css|doc|eot|flv|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|pdf|png|rtf|swf|txt|woff|xml)(\?.*)?$") {
        unset req.http.Cookie;
        return (hash);
    }

    if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(mp[34]|rar|tar|tgz|gz|wav|zip|bz2|xz|7z|avi|mov|ogm|mpe?g|mk[av]|webm)(\?.*)?$") {
        unset req.http.Cookie;
        return (hash);
    }

    if(req.http.Accept-Encoding) 
    {
       if(req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp[34]|ogg)$")
       {
        # No point compressing these extensions
        unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
       } elsif(req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") 
       {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
       } elsif(req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") 
       {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
       } elsif(req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "sdch") 
       {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "sdch";
       } else 
       {
        # Unknown Algorithm
        unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
       }
    }

}

# At this point, it is our last chance to make some decision (set|unset|mod) about some header that the backend should see.

sub vcl_backend_fetch {

    unset bereq.http.X-Varnish-SESS-ID;
}


sub vcl_hit {

    # Custom Headers for debug purposes
    set req.http.X-Cache-TTL-Remaining = obj.ttl;
    set req.http.X-Cache-Age = obj.keep - obj.ttl;
    set req.http.X-Cache-Grace = obj.grace;
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    if (bereq.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(mp[34]|rar|tar|tgz|gz|wav|zip|bz2|xz|7z|avi|mov|ogm|mpe?g|mk[av]|webm)(\?.*)?$") {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        set beresp.do_stream = true;  # Check memory usage it'll grow in fetch_chunksize blocks (128k by default) if the backend doesn't send a Content-Length header, so only enable it for big objects
        set beresp.do_gzip = false;   # Don't try to compress it for storage
    }

    # Do not Gzip image files in Varnish
    if (beresp.http.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|mp4|ogg|swf)$") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = false;
    }
    else {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
        set beresp.http.X-Cache = "ZIP";
    }

    # GZip the cached content if possible
    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    # If we are performing a redirection 301 / 302 from the backend and our web server and varnish instances are in the same node, apache mod_rewrite could append it's port
    # typically varnish :80 apache/nginx/lighthttp :8080, so the redirect can then often redirect the end-user to a URL on :8080, where it should be :80.

    if(beresp.status == 301 || beresp.status == 302) {
        set beresp.http.Location = regsub(beresp.http.Location, ":[0-9]+", "");
    }

    # The example below is explained in detail in load_balancing.vcl as part of one of the strategies that we can take to handle Varnish Grace Mode

    set bereq.http.stale-while-revalidate = regsub(beresp.http.Cache-Control, ".*stale-while-revalidate\=([0-9]+).*", "\1");

    if(std.real(bereq.http.stale-while-revalidate, 0.0) > 0)
    {
        set beresp.grace = std.duration(bereq.http.stale-while-revalidate + "s", 10s);
    } else {
        set beresp.grace = 2h;
    }

}

sub vcl_deliver {

    # At this point this is our last change to set or unset the response headers before deliver it

    if (obj.hits > 0) 
    {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
    } else 
    {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }

    set resp.http.X-Hits = obj.hits;

    # Remove www of our host in the backend response
    set resp.http.X-Host = regsub(req.http.host, "^www\.", "");

    # Remove PHP , Apache and Varnish versions
    unset resp.http.x-powered-by;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;

    # Here we are ensuring to add this headers in the response (defined in the hit subroutine) for debug purposes
    set resp.http.X-Cache-TTL-Remaining = req.http.X-Cache-TTL-Remaining;
    set resp.http.X-Cache-Age = req.http.X-Cache-Age;
    set resp.http.X-Cache-Grace = req.http.X-Cache-Grace;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The varnish log you are providing does not match the curl request you are doing (wrong user agent for example).

If it is still relevant, in your varnishlog you can see that the backend request contains the headers :

```
BereqHeader    Cache-Control: no-cache
BereqHeader    Pragma: no-cache
```

and the backend response contains the following

```
BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

which prevent Varnish from caching the response.

Can you share the varnish log part for the Request (not the BackendRequest) ?

Without it, my guess could be that you always get a miss because the builtin.vcl make your request a `pass` (you do not do any `return (pass)` in your conf nonetheless the backend request comes from the `pass` state

```
Begin          bereq 1048612 pass
```

It could be triggered by these two rules in the builtin.vcl :

```
if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
    /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
    return (pass);
}
if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
    /* Not cacheable by default */
    return (pass);
}
```

**EDIT**

That's weird. You should not have any Cookie using Curl.
Try scoping your cookie handling code and use req.http.Cookie (with an uppercase C) like this :

```
if (req.http.Cookie) {
  # Remove Google Analytics Cookies, our server does not need it
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__utm.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_ga=[^;]+(; )?", "");
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_gat=[^;]+(; )?", "");
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmctr=[^;]+(; )?", "");
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmcmd.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmccn.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  # Remove DoubleClick offensive cookies
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__gads=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  # Remove the Quant Capital cookies (added by some plugin, all __qca)
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__qc.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  # Remove the AddThis cookies
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__atuv.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  # Remove a ";" prefix in the cookie if present
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");

  # Are there cookies left with only spaces or that are empty?
  if (req.http.Cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
      unset req.http.Cookie;
  }
}
```

Another thing here, in your vcl log you can see that Varnish is doing Hit-For-Pass, that is, Varnish is caching the fact that your request is not cached. If you want to truly test, you'll need to purge the content beforehands.
One last thing : your backend server (apache) responds with a `Cache-Control : max-age =0` header which prevent caching, you should change that if you want to cache content.

Comment: Hey Benjamin, I'm very thankful for you answer. I'm not very familiar with Varnish and debugging responses - please excuse me for providing the wrong logfiles.
I did a new request to Varnish in order to get you a correct log of the requests. I edited them into my question. I guess that the Varnish passes because of any cookies left.. what do you think?